# Send and Receive google text message SMS VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sms

I am trying to send and receive SMS messages. Sending is not a problem and that part works well, but I also need to get the responses back.

For example on the TV you often see things that say something like "Text sales to 884921"

Something on the other end must be reading those text messages and handling them. Another example is AT&T sends out a text message that says something like "You bill is ready, text YES to pay the bill now".  This is exactly what I need to do.  If I were writing the app on the Android or iPhone it would be easier as the text messaging is already there.

I was thinking I could use Google voice text messaging, but I need it to be automated with an app that I write on my server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Google Voice won't do that for you.  Try Twilio.

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://www.textanywhere.net/ in the past for text polling, and using vb.net too.  You just add the web service reference to a project that runs every X amount of seconds as a scheduled task (based on how often you want to check for replies).  They have good documentation on their site too that should detail everything you need.