# Send sms from vb.net application using cell phone

Tags: vb.net, sms, send, mobile-phones, cellular-network

I am developing a software that generates bills for customers in VB.Net. Am using vs2010 on windows 7 and connecting my PC to Android cell phone. I want to send sms to all customers from my application through the cell phone. The cell phone of course has SIM card to call and send sms. I need the code that does this job.

Comment: You didn't indicate whether your PC would be connected to an iPhone, a Blackberry, an Android, a Windows Phone phone, or a Windows Mobile phone, and these all would have different programming characteristics.

It isn't clear why you need to use the phone to send the text message. Perhaps looking at other [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196225/send-and-receive-google-text-message-sms-vb-net?rq=1) questions would help you find your answer.

Comment: These devices would look the same from a PC though (apart from minor AT command differences if you're pre Win 7).

Answer (score 2):

You need to send AT commands to the modem port on which your cell phone is connected, if your PC is XP or Vista.  If it's Win 7 or 8, you can use the Windows Mobile Broadband API to send an SMS.  If you're developing in the-interface-formerly-known-as-Metro, there is another API equivalent to MB API.

Comment: Am having windows 7 and I u mentioned i would need windows mobile broadband API, but how to use it?

Comment: Google "mobile broadband api reference" to find the Microsoft documentation.  There is a useful paper on implementing it from C# here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487392.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered integrating with [Twilio](http://twilio.com)? They even have some [handy .NET libraries](http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries) making this dropdead easy.